# How do you set a value in the IntelliJ Registry?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I override a value that is used internally in IntelliJ, for example this expression:

```
Registry.intValue("a.b.c")
```

I can access the registry `Registry.getInstance()` but it doesn't allow updating any key/value pairs.

Any tips?

Comment: I want to override `Registry.intValue("ide.max.recent.projects")`. I can't find it in any files in `.IntelliJ14` or subfolders, therefore I conclude it comes from static configuration and would like to override it at runtime. (And yes, I routinely work in more than 25 projects)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> and select "Registry" from the menu that appears.

(If that keyboard shortcut is not working for you, use your configured keyboard shortcut for `Find Action`. On Mac by default it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, on Windows it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ([docs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/top-15-intellij-idea-shortcuts/)). Then type "Registry" and click or hit enter.)

Comment: I would guess that OS X users need to use Command instead of Control.

Comment: Btw, this apparently isn'y  available in Android Studio, any ideas?

Comment: I think they disabled this action.

Comment: Okay. You can do it via code like so: `Registry.get(KEY).setValue(123);`

Comment: With newer version of Intellij, you can just double press **Shift**, click on **Action** panel and type Registry

Answer (score 9):

If you are using OS X, you can open the registry by typing 'cmd + shift + A'. Type 'registry' and change the value of the option you're looking for.
In this [source](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/intellij-idea-spring-boot-template-reload-is-not-working/) you can see an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the registry entries you have modified here:

(Modify the version to your installed IDE version)

IntelliJ:

```
/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/options/ide.general.xml
```

Android Studio:

```
/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/options/ide.general.xml
```

It'll look something like this:

```
<application>
    <component name="Registry">
        <entry key="unknown.sdk.auto" value="1337" />            
    </component>
    <component name="StatusBar">
        <option name="widgets">
            <map>
                <entry key="Memory" value="true" />                    
            </map>
        </option>
    </component>        
</application>
```

And in the IDE:

[image]