# IntelliJ IDEA spring boot hot reload on manual save?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

My goal is:

1. Disable autosave in IntelliJ IDEA for a spring boot project
2. Hot reload the project always when files are manually saved

Seems to me that it is impossible to achieve these two goals simultaneously.

I can disable autosave in IntelliJ IDEA by modifying these settings:

**Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Compiler** Uncheck Build project automatically

Also I think what is too needed is modify these options:

**Appearance & Behaviour** -> **System Settings** Uncheck both save files under Synchronization (frame deactivation and save files automatically)

I can enable hot reload by the help of Mkyong: [Mkyong-help](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/intellij-idea-spring-boot-template-reload-is-not-working/)
As you can see from the link, it requires setting 'Build project automatically' on. If I do both of these steps, then the application will always save on edit, and it will always hot reload the app.

This is so frustrating, I thought IntelliJ IDEA was a good modern IDE, with these kind of industrial core features like hot reloading handled easy?

**The problem is, that I really don't want to hot reload my application on every change I make to the files!** Because then it will be continuously hot reloading, which will break the application most of the time. Just so unnecessary and wasting resources. I want to hot reload always when I manually save a file, which is a standard for so many other editors. There has to be a solution for this problem, because people want reasonable hot reload for their development.

Comment: How about assigning `Build` | `Build Project` to Ctrl+S?

Answer (score 24):

**As far as I understand**, your issue is that you want the spring server to reload automatically whenever you make changes and then manually save them. Right? if the that is the case, follow my steps and **hopefully** you will get what desire.

### 1. include the spring-boot-devtools dependency

#### Maven

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

### 2.  enable “Make project automatically” in the compiler preferences for automatic restarts to work.

[image]

### 3. enable the `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` registry setting in IntelliJ.  You can access the registry in IntelliJ using the shortcut `Shift+Command+A`, then searching for registry.

[image]

---

The 3rd step will make building  your project (make project) automatic when you save you changes manually.

========================================================================
These steps will enforce spring server to reboot once changes has been saved manually via your IDE. However, you need to refresh your browser every time you make a change even though the server is rebooted. To enforce your browser to refresh automatically as well, you need an extension installed in your browser called Live Reload. Check this link http://livereload.com/extensions/. the link will show you how to install this extension depends on your browser.

Comment: This works for me, but I feel there is some delay in triggering it up after I hit `Cmd+S` to save. Is there any delay to decrease in those registry settings?

Comment: For someone who do not know how to open the Registry setting, reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415695/how-do-you-set-a-value-in-the-intellij-registry

Comment: If you are using OS X, you can open the registry by typing 'cmd + shift + A'. Type 'registry' and change the value of the option you're looking for.

Comment: @krozaine did you manage to solve the delay? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Mirceac21 there is `compiler.automake.trigger.delay` in registry settings. Please check if this helps

Comment: I know its an old question.. but.
In the current Version of IntelliJ the 'compiler.automate...' registry setting is not longer available. Does anyone know something about an new option?

Comment: @Yannick you can find it under "Advanced Settings", it's called "Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running". Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730328

Comment: how i can have this set up especially for the separated servers as well as git server, I only have to have this thing set up and it will automatically build and deploy to the webserver?

Answer (score 6):

In IntelliJ 2021.2
you only have to click this option
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-1125614?sign=MTYzMDgwMDAwMDAwMHwxMS04NzUyMzF8NzQtMTEyNTYxNHxON0lqdXpkVUo4ZG1VOGlqMjRsQkY3%0D%0AVjRXbHJlQ1oxM0hfaE0tVGd0cG9zDQo%0D%0A&updated=1627651335092

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple workflow that works well for me in IDEA Ultimate Edition and **does not restart parts of the application** when the code is hot swapped:

### 1. Install Spring Boot Developer Tools

- This is a first step in every guide out there, just [follow the instructions in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools)

### 2. Create a proper Spring Boot run configuration

**The crucial step here is to set the `On 'Update' action` to `Hot swap classes and update trigger file if failed`**
[image: Settings]
Here's the tooltip's explanation of the various options. Specifying only `Update classes or resources` would work, but parts of your application would be reloaded, but much faster than if you started the application from scratch. See the `Restart vs Reload` [section of the documentation for an explanation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-restart).
[image: Tooltip]

### 3. Run your Spring Boot application in debug mode `Shift + F9`

### 4. Change some java files or static content and press `CTRL + F10`

It will update classes and resources you just changed. For good results, disable your browser's cache to avoid seeing old versions of static resources.

### 5. Editing templates

If you're using templating engines, the documentation provides instructions about [how to reload them without restarting the container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-hotswapping)

### 6. (Optional) Trigger a browser refresh with LiveReload

Spring Boot Developer Tools [contain a LiveReload server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-livereload) which helps you trigger browser reloads whenever the content changes.

Comment: There is another way here (under updated) that does not involve manually updating application (CTRL-F10) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839843/springboot-update-classes-without-restarting-tomcat-server

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Below Version of Community Edition

[IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2(Community Edition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzkK6.png)

And Below Are the Steps I performed to Hot Reload on Manual Save.

**Step 1**
added spring-boot-dev-tools dependency in Maven dependency **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

**Step 2**
[Compiler Configuration for picking build Automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU5Z6.png)

**Step 3**
[Advance Compiler Setting for Restart on Manual Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x46Ei.png)