# Big line number columns in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

My line number column width in intellij idea is weird.

Its a lot big when tabs are closed:

[image]

If I expand any of tab, it looks like this:

[image]

Is this feature or bug? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure "editor.distraction.free.mode" isn't enabled in [Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415695/how-do-you-set-a-value-in-the-intellij-registry). Otherwise this is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002