# How to make it faster when scrolling though tab in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, scroll, tabs

It is quite slow to scroll through tabs in Idea. I am happy about the speed it scroll through files, but for tabs it is too slow.
[image]

Is there a way to keep the general scroll speed but make it faster only when scrolling through tabs?

I am aware that there are hotkeys to switch tabs quickly, but still need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED 05.2023**

Apparently, the bug has reappeared in the `2023.1.1` version of IntelliJ and was fixed in [2023.1.2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-318576/Editor-tabs-scroll-very-slowly)
Also the registry key ide.editor.tabs.scroll.unit.increment is gone!

**FOR OLD VERSIONS**

Indeed in the current build 2020.3.1 tabs scrolling is very slow.  There is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233135) for it, and apparently, JetBrains already fixed it. Here are official comments from a [developer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233135#focus=Comments-27-4633405.0-0):

These three problems were fixed:

1. For slow mouse wheel rotation we should use "rough" integer metrics event.getUnitsToScroll() instead of "precise" double metrics event.getPreciseWheelRotation(). Actually is means 1 instead of 0.1 in my environment (MacBook)
2. In MacBooks trackpad can suddenly send a single scroll event in opposite direction and looks like "trembling", these sudden events should be ignored
3. Unit increment for horizontal scrolling can be tuned now with registry key ide.editor.tabs.scroll.unit.increment (default value is 10)

See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/7b1920aad803292267a22b7e352527c627093da0?branch=7b1920aad803292267a22b7e352527c627093da0&diff=split) for the relevant changes.

As for versions of IntelliJ:

1. 2020.3.1 the bug exists and you can do nothing about it, is suppose, without altering the speed of scrolling in the main window.
2. 2021.1 the bug was fixed. Currently (23.01.2020), you can't download it, but I think it will be available soon as EAP Build. Please, [see here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Latest+builds).
3. If you want it right now, you can download the source code and build it manually from the [git repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community). The build instructions are simple. I tested it, and indeed, the scrolling is much faster now :)

Additionally, after the availability of 2021.1 build, you can modify the speed of tab scrolling by changing the [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419108/5681468) value `ide.editor.tabs.scroll.unit.increment`

Comment: May 2023: the bug has reappeared, but the registry entry has gone.
seems there is no workaround and we need jetbrains to publish a new fix.

Comment: @AdrianC, What is your current version of the IDE?

Comment: Got bug on 2023.1.1 and no option in registry :(  (EDIT: Just updated to 2023.1.2 and scrolling speed is much better!)