# How to prevent focus from wrapping around?

Tags: intellij-idea, user-experience

When using keyboard navigation in the project files or variables tabs, focus wraps around from the first entry in the list to the last one, and vice-versa.

Is there a way to disable focus from wrapping around? I want navigation to stop at the top and bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262817 you can disable `ide.cycle.scrolling` in the [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419108/14731).